# check if a string A an anagram of a substring of another string B

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, substring, anagram

Rotate a given string(A) in specified direction by specified magnitude. After each rotation, make a note of first character of the rotated string. Once all the rotations are performed, the accumulated first characters of all rotated strings, constitute another string(B). Check if B is an anagram of any substring of A.
Note: Every rotation is to be performed on the original string A.

**Input format:**
First line of input contains T - number of test cases. First line of each test case contains A - original string. Second line of each test case contains Q - denoting number of queries (rotations). Each of the next Q lines contains 2 values D, M seperated by space, where D denotes direction of rotation and M denotes magnitude of rotation.

constraints:

```
1 <= size(A) <= 10^5 
0 <= M <= 10^5
1 <= T <= 100
'a' <= A[i] <= 'z'
1 <= Q <= size(A).
```

*I keep getting key error for line 35. I tried to trace it out but it's not working. Any help is appreciated.*

```
def create(s):
    d={}
    for x in s:
        if x in d:
            d[x]+=1
        else:
            d[x]=1
    return d
def check(a, b):
    for x in a:
        if x not in b or a[x]!=b[x]:
            return False
    return True
def find(s, res):
    m = len(s)
    n = len(res)
    if n>m:# if len(res)>len(s) return False
        return False
    dres = create(res)#dict for the res string
    ds={}# dict for the original string, sliding window to be performed on this dict
    for i in range(n):
        if s[i] in ds:
            ds[s[i]]+=1
        else:
            ds[s[i]]=1
    if check(dres, ds):#check if the dictionaries are same
        return True
    for i in range(n, m):
        #updating the dict for the original string for the incoming character
        if s[i] in ds:
            ds[s[i]]+=1
        else:
            ds[s[i]]=1
        #updating the dict for the original string for the outgoing character
        ds[s[i-n]]-=1
        if ds[s[i-n]]==0:
            ds.pop(ds[s[i-n]])
        if check(dres, ds):
            return True
    return False
        
for _ in range(int(input())):
    s = input()
    l=len(s)
    n=int(input())
    res=''
    while(n>0):
        temp = list(input().split())
        if temp[0]=="L":
            res+=s[int(temp[1])]
        elif temp[0]=="R":
            res+=s[l - int(temp[1])]
        n-=1
    if find(s, res):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

**INPUT:**

```
2
abcdef
3
L 1
L 5
R 3
markram
3
L 2
R 2
L 3
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
No
Yes
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by rotation.  An example of the step by step process would also help

Comment: @nobleknight i am getting the KeyError: 0 for line 37

Comment: @itprorh66 
By rotating string "abcdef" in left direction by magnitude 1, rotated string is bcdefa and the first character is 'b'.
By rotating string "abcdef" in left direction by magnitude 5, rotated string is fabcde and the first character is 'f'.
By rotating string "abcdef" in right direction by magnitude 3, rotated string is defabc and the first character is 'd'.
String attained by accumulating all the first characters is "bfd", which is not an anagram of any substring of "abcdef".